# Ajax Modal Popup Display Issue

Tags: modalpopupextender

On the web page, there is gridview control contains product ID's. bind to a link button.

On ItemCommand event of gridview, I fetch the product information and display in the ajax modal popup extender control. The popup is programatically show on ItemCommand of gridview and also hide programatically.

Now the problem is that, when i close popup after showing first product details and try to see next 1 by clicking on other product ID.., sometimes details are displaye dand sometimes not.

The data comes from database is fetched as well for each product.

Plz help.

Answer (score 0):

I do the same but i have no such problem. So i am pasting code here that may b help full to u.
**CODE:**

```
protected void GVallusers_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            GridViewRow gvRow = ((GridView)sender).Rows[e.NewEditIndex];
            populatepanel(gvRow);
            ModalPopupExtender1.Show();
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            lblinfo.Text = exc.Message;
        }
    }

public void populatepanel(GridViewRow gvrow)
    {      
        string userid = gvrow.Cells[0].Text;
        lblSite.Text=gvrow.Cells[1].Text;
        lblemail.Text = gvrow.Cells[3].Text;
    }
```